# I am trying to find the equation for the waveform for some binary numbers

Tags: java, c#, binary, trigonometry

I'm trying to find out the equation or formula  (e.g. xcos(t)+ysin(t)) that points to each specific binary number on the constellation graph. Can anyone help me with a method to find the formulas ? I attached an image with the constellation graph.

[This image contains the numbers with the position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDD7y.jpg)

Comment: Draw a triangle.  You have a vector going from the origin (0,0) to each point.  So if you have point (1,3)  The angle is arcTan(3/1).

Comment: You're looking for an equation here, rather than code, so I'd suggest posting to our mathematics sister site: https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: can you please give me an example @jdweng